# What is the best way to get an image URL from a certain query?

Tags: vb.net, image, search

I have a book recommendation project for school, and I want to add a picture for each book.  I was thinking I could use a search engine API to return the first result, but I'm having trouble with them:

- The Google .NET Api seems to be unsupported
- The Bing API
- The Flickr Api is well documented and it actually works, but the images on there aren't what I'm looking for

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried http://jpg.to ?

`[searchterm].jpg.to`

i.e.

http://programmingfordummies.jpg.to/

http://clockworkorange.jpg.to/

http://fantasticmrfox.jpg.to/

Comment: It seems .net cannot load images from that site into a picturebox, probably because of the ".to" but this is still a great resource I will probably use in the future.

Comment: create a stream, load the image into that then to the picture box, you're probably correct with the .to part. Or you could parse the html of the page, the only thing in the page source is `<img>` so you could grab the image url from `src=""`.